# Is there any way to run/execute cells after a certain cell in Databrick notebook?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

I'm wondering if it is possible to run cells **after a certain cell** on Databricks notebook instead of `Run All` option on top of notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click onto the keyboard symbol in the menu, it will show you available shortcuts. What you need is `<Shift>+<Option>+<Down>: Run all below commands (inclusive)` (on Mac, on Window it could be slightly different combination). Or if you click onto the dropdown symbol of `>` character, you will see "Run all below" (see the [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#run-all-above-or-below))

Comment: Thanks for your input. I could find it as you mentioned [here](https://i.imgur.com/nxL40H1.jpg) but I couldn't find shortcut for windows.

Comment: I think that it could be `<ctrl>-<win-key>-<down>`

Comment: I’ve filed request to expand it for windows and Linux as well